# ¿Cómo extraer el link de una imagen de una cadena HTML en SQL?

Tags: sql-server

¿Podrían ayudarme con esta consulta?

Necesito extraer el link de una imagen que está en código html (únicamente el link, sin el src ni las comillas) es posible?

Estuve investigando un poco y encontré que se puede hacer haciendo uso de **CHARINDEX** y **SUBSTRING**, lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
DECLARE @Cadena VARCHAR(MAX),
@Valor VARCHAR(MAX),
@Longitud INT

SET @Cadena = `<img id="bigpic" itemprop="image" src="https://www.cyamoda.com/12300-cart_default/caballero-camisas-camisa-de-mezclilla-1044207-prod.jpg" title="Camisa de mezclilla" alt="Camisa de mezclilla" width="458" height="590">`
SET @Valor = 'src'
SET @Longitud = LEN(@Valor)

SELECT
SUBSTRING(@Cadena,CHARINDEX(@Valor,@Cadena),@Longitud)
```

Pero no me sirve ya que solo me arroja “src” cómo valor, no el link cómo tal,¿Qué es lo que me falta o cuál sería la forma correcta de obtenerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que indicar entre qué delimitadores se encuentra la cadena para poder extraerla.

Dado que las comillas `"` aparecen varias veces en la cadena, no puedes usar las comillas que hay al final de la URL.

Una posibilidad, que puede ser precaria en el sentido de que si no hay siempre la palabra `title` después de la URL va a fallar consistiría en esto:

```
DECLARE @Cadena VARCHAR(MAX), @Inicio VARCHAR(MAX), @Fin VARCHAR(MAX), @PosInicio int,  @PosFin int 
SET @Cadena = '<img id="bigpic" itemprop="image" src="https://www.cyamoda.com/12300-cart_default/caballero-camisas-camisa-de-mezclilla-1044207-prod.jpg" title="Camisa de mezclilla" alt="Camisa de mezclilla" width="458" height="590">'
SET @Inicio = 'src="'
SET @Fin = '" title'
-- Determinamos donde empezará la subcadena
SET @PosInicio = CHARINDEX(@Inicio,@Cadena) + LEN(@Inicio)
-- Determinamos donde terminará la subcadena
SET @PosFin = CHARINDEX(@Fin,@Cadena)
-- La extraemos con substring
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Cadena, @PosInicio, @PosFin - @PosInicio) as URL;
```

**Salida:**

```
https://www.cyamoda.com/12300-cart_default/caballero-camisas-camisa-de-mezclilla-1044207-prod.jpg
```

Aquí simplemente se busca el dato que hay entre `src="` y `" title`. Si los datos vienen estandarizados así no hay problema. Si no, tendrás que buscar otro delimitador, por ejemplo, si las extensiones son siempre `.jpg` sería un delimitador interesante para extraer la cadena.

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes hacerlo con substring, pero es un pelín más complicado.
Te voy a poner la secuencia completa, aunque realmente se puede hacer directamente en una sola sentencia. Pero no es nada didáctico.

```
DECLARE @Cadena VARCHAR(MAX), @Valor VARCHAR(MAX), @LongitudDesdeSrc INT,     @LongitudHastaFinalCadena INT;

SET @Cadena = '<img id="bigpic" itemprop="image" src="https://www.cyamoda.com /12300-cart_default/caballero-camisas-camisa-de-mezclilla-1044207-prod.jpg" title="Camisa de mezclilla" alt="Camisa de mezclilla" width="458" height="590">';

SET @Valor = 'src='; -- parte a buscar para el inicio.

SET @LongitudDesdeSrc = CHARINDEX(@Valor, @Cadena) + 5;

SET @LongitudHastaFinalCadena = CHARINDEX('"', @cadena, (CHARINDEX(@Valor, @Cadena)  + 5));

SELECT SUBSTRING(@CADENA, @LONGITUDDESDESRC, @LONGITUDHASTAFINALCADENA - @LongitudDesdeSrc);
```

Lo primero es encontrar src= cuando tienes el punto de inicio de esa parte, es donde empezará el substring, luego hay que encontrar la siguiente comilla doble, que hay despues de src=", que es donde termina. Pero como substring busca un punto de inicio y la longitud, pues a esa longitud le tienes que quitar la parte del inicio.

El resultado es:

[image: Resultado]